# Android Volley get request, my onResponse never gets called

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I know this question has been asked a few times and i have tried all the solutions however, nothing seems to work. My method:

```
    public static LocationGeoData getLocationGeoData(Location location){

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MyApplication.getAppContext());
        Date dateNow = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");

        String url = "MYCORRECTURL";
        Log.d("geoData", "In getGeoData  " + url); // this is called and logs
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        Log.d("geoData", "inside the response");// this never gets called

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("data");
                            for(int i = 0; i <jsonObject.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject heading = jsonObject;
                                if(heading.getString("field-value").equals("field-value")){
                                    JSONObject totIntensity = heading.getJSONObject("total-intensity");
                                    JSONObject declination = heading.getJSONObject("declination");
                                    JSONObject inclination = heading.getJSONObject("inclination");

                                    int totalIntensity = totIntensity.getInt("value");
                                    double declinationValue = declination.getDouble("value");
                                    double inclinationValue = inclination.getDouble("value");

                                    locationGeoData = new LocationGeoData(totalIntensity, declinationValue, inclinationValue);

                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.d("geoData", "Error recorded");//never called
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("geoData", "Error recorded");// never called
            }

        });
        requestQueue.add(request);
        return locationGeoData;
    }
```

The second Log message inside the response never gets called, i get no error messages, my url works and i can see the JsonOBject in the browser when tested, but the response is never called in my method. Can anyone advise me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You have 2 issues; order of events and scope. The method returns before the listener is triggered (i.e. before the network response), and the object the listener is attached to falls out of scope before the network response.

Comment: See my post here for the easiest solution to this asynchronicity problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62855046/13373270.

Comment: @codebod I can see your solution and it looks great, i would like to try to implement the request as it is done in every tutorial i can see out there, How could i return or save my LocationGeoData Object in my current implementation? Is that possible, i can see how the callback pattern would work but i would liek ot keep it a little more simple isf that is possible? do you know how i could do that? Thanks codebod

Comment: You can see that the `onResponse` method is `void`; it returns nothing. Your `getGeoLocationData` method cannot return your network response as the method will always finish before the response listener is triggered. Use the callback pattern.